# I can't figure out what is wrong my implementation of MST with Kruskal algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to solve an algorithm problem (MST with Kruskal algorithm). It works sometimes and doesn't work sometimes (with runtime error). I solved this problem with another approach, but I want to figure out what is wrong with this code for future problems. I guess it is the memory problem, but I can't find out for two days.

```
typedef struct edges
{
    struct edges *nextNode;
    int weight;
    int src;
    int dest;
}EDGES;

typedef struct vertex
{
    EDGES *edgePtr;
    int verNum;
    int weight;
    COLOR color;
}VERTEX;

typedef struct setTree
{
    struct setTree *parent;
    int verNum;
    int rank;
}SETNODE;

SETNODE *findSet(SETNODE *tree)
{
    if (tree != tree->parent)
        tree->parent = findSet(tree->parent);
    return tree->parent;
}

void makeSet(SETNODE *tree, int vernum)
{
    tree->parent = tree;
    tree->verNum = vernum;
    tree->rank = 0;
}

int linkSet(SETNODE *x, SETNODE *y)
{
    SETNODE *x_root = findSet(x);
    SETNODE *y_root = findSet(y);

    if (x_root->rank > y_root->rank)
        y_root->parent = x_root;
    else if (x_root->rank < y_root->rank)
    {
        x_root->parent = y_root;
    }
    else
    {
        y_root->parent = x_root;
        ++x_root->rank;
    }

    return 1;
}

int unionSet(SETNODE *x, SETNODE *y)
{
    return linkSet(x, y);
}

void MST_Kruskal(VERTEX **graph, int N, EDGES **edgeList, int edgeNum)
{
    SETNODE *set[MAXN];
    EDGES *result[MAXN*(MAXN - 1)];
    EDGES *tmp[MAXN];
    int edgeCnt = 0;
    int tmpVerNum1, tmpVerNum2;


    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        set[i] = new SETNODE;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        makeSet(set[i], (i + 1));
    }

    mergeSort(edgeList, tmp, 0, edgeNum - 1);

    /*for (int i = 0; i < edgeNum; ++i)
    printf("%d->%d : %d\n", edgeList[i]->src, edgeList[i]->dest, edgeList[i]->weight);
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < edgeNum; ++i)
    {
        tmpVerNum1 = edgeList[i]->src; tmpVerNum2 = edgeList[i]->dest;

        if (findSet(set[tmpVerNum1 - 1]) != findSet(set[tmpVerNum2 - 1]))
        {
            int success = unionSet(set[tmpVerNum1 - 1], set[tmpVerNum2 - 1]);
            if (success)
                result[edgeCnt++] = edgeList[i];
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", edgeCnt);
    for (int i = 0; i < edgeCnt; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", result[i]->src, result[i]->dest, result[i]->weight);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        delete set[i];
    }
}
```

For mergeSort, there's some kind of restriction with this problem that if weight is same between edges, there should be less vertex number first.

```
void merge(EDGES **arr, EDGES **tmp, int left, int middle, int right)
{
    int i = left, j = middle + 1, k = left, l;

    while (i <= middle && j <= right)
    {
        if (arr[i]->weight < arr[j]->weight)
        {
            tmp[k++] = arr[i++];
        }
        else if (arr[i]->weight == arr[j]->weight)
        {
            if (arr[i]->src < arr[j]->src)
                tmp[k++] = arr[i++];
            else if (arr[i]->src == arr[j]->src)
            {
                if (arr[i]->dest <= arr[j]->dest)
                    tmp[k++] = arr[i++];
                else
                    tmp[k++] = arr[j++];
            }
            else
                tmp[k++] = arr[j++];
        }
        else
        {
            tmp[k++] = arr[j++];
        }
    }
    if (i > middle)
    {
        for (l = j; l <= right; l++)
        {
            tmp[k++] = arr[l];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (l = i; l <= middle; l++)
        {
            tmp[k++] = arr[l];
        }
    }


    for (l = left; l <= right; l++)
    {
        arr[l] = tmp[l];
    }

}


void mergeSort(EDGES **arr, EDGES **tmp, int left, int right)
{
    int middle = (left + right) / 2;

    if (left < right)
    {
        mergeSort(arr, tmp, left, middle);
        mergeSort(arr, tmp, middle + 1, right);
        merge(arr, tmp, left, middle, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: First — choose your language.  Don't dual tag with both the [tag:c] and [tag:c++] tags unless you are asking about a difference between the languages, or the interworking of the languages.  Using both tags has a tendency to annoy people.  Choose one — the code looks like C++ (`new`), so probably remove the C tag.

Comment: Did you run it in a debugger to find out where it crashes? Can you provide a complete example including any input required to make it crash?

Comment: *but I can't find out for two days.* -- Then you are not using a debugger, or you do not understand your own code, or you don't know C++ enough, or a combination of those items.  It shouldn't take 2 days to, at the very least, determine *where* the problem is, even pinpoint the function(s) that are causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the fewer pointers you use means you are less likely to run into memory problems. Make sure that you aren't accidentally accessing members of a `nullptr`, or forgetting to pass an address to a function. It would be helpful if you could give us more information on the error :)

Here is an implementation of Kruskal that I wrote a while back. It makes heavy use of the STL and no pointers while simulating a linked list for the `EdgeList` using a pre-allocated array:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

const int MAXSZ = 1010;
struct Edge
{
    static int cnt;
    int from, to, weight, next;
} edges[MAXSZ * 2], full[MAXSZ * 2];
int Edge::cnt = 1;
int head[MAXSZ]; // for EdgeList impl
int bigb[MAXSZ]; // for DisjointSet impl

int find(const int c) // DisjointSet `find`
{
    if (bigb[c] == c)
        return c;
    bigb[c] = find(bigb[c]);
    return bigb[c];
}

void addEdge(const int a, const int b, const int w) // add edges to EdgeList from pure data
{
    edges[Edge::cnt].from = a;
    edges[Edge::cnt].to = b;
    edges[Edge::cnt].weight = w;
    edges[Edge::cnt].next = head[a];
    head[a] = Edge::cnt;
    ++Edge::cnt;

    bigb[find(a)] = bigb[find(b)] = std::min(find(a), find(b)); // needed to init DisjointSet
}

void addEdge(const Edge &base) // copy insert to EdgeList
{
    edges[Edge::cnt] = base;
    edges[Edge::cnt].next = head[base.from];
    head[base.from] = Edge::cnt;
    ++Edge::cnt;

    bigb[find(base.from)] = bigb[find(base.to)] = std::min(find(base.from), find(base.to));
}

int main()
{
    int m, n;
    scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
    auto cmp = [](const int &l, const int &r) { return full[l].weight > full[r].weight; };
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::function<bool(int, int)> > pq(cmp); // Used for kruskal
    /* input */
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        int a, b, w;
        scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &w);
        full[i].from = a;
        full[i].to = b;
        full[i].weight = w;
        pq.push(i);

        bigb[full[i].from] = full[i].from;
        bigb[full[i].to] = full[i].to;
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int vis = 0; !pq.empty(); pq.pop())
    {
        auto cur = full[pq.top()];
        if (find(cur.to) == vis && find(cur.from) == vis)
            continue; // if it leads back to something we already have
        addEdge(cur);
        addEdge(cur.to, cur.from, cur.weight); // other direction
        vis = std::min(find(cur.to), find(cur.from));
        printf("%d -> %d, %d\n", cur.from, cur.to, cur.weight);
        sum += cur.weight;
        //debug*/ for (int i=1; i<=m; ++i) printf("%3d", i); printf("\n"); for (int i=1; i<=m; ++i) printf("%3d", bigb[i]); printf("\n\n");
    }

    printf("total: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}

/* test data
first line: verticies, edges
next #edges lines: from, to, weight
3 3
1 2 3
3 2 1
3 1 2

5 6
1 2 2
1 4 1
2 3 2
3 4 -2
3 5 1
4 5 9
*/
```

Comment: Given the original poster said that they were solving an "algorithm problem" I assume competitive programming, for which `scanf` tends to be preferred for speed, although I concede that that indeed introduces near-pointer experiences. Should I still change to `cin` and `cout`?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo I have inserted the proper `std::` prefixes. Is that better?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem lies in the declaration of `tmp` array. You have used it as a temporary array for the `merge` function in `mergeSort`.
I am assuming `maxN` is the maximum number of vertices in the graph. Hence the maximum number of edges in the graph can be `maxN*(maxN-1)`. You have declared the size of `result` to be that and not `tmp` when infact the size of result should be `maxN` (`maxN-1` to be precise since it will consist of edges representing a MST at the end) and the size of `tmp` should be `maxN*(maxN-1)` since the size of `edgeList` (which is being sorted using `tmp` array), i.e., `edgeNum` can be anywhere between `0` and `maxN*(maxN-1)`.

Comment: yes, you are right. Thank you. It was obvious, How can't I see this for 2 days...